# Xamarin Forms - Android xamarin.android.support.CusomtTabs

Tags: android, asp.net, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

we are working on a big xamarin forms project, and after almost finishing every thing, an error appeared to us we don't know why and how, the error is:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     Exception while loading assemblies:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android
>   profile? File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() ......****

Any help in this please

Comment: Are you trying to use this [Android Support Custom Tabs Library](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportcustomtabs)? Have you correctly installed this package in your project?

Comment: thank you for your response, I was trying to install it but it give me dependency error, just I downgrade the version of this library and its working fine now, thank you again